# ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence deploying with maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.
But when I deploy the application in maven I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
```

This is my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <!-- <version>1.3</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
          <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.10</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- HIBERNATE LIBRARIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2_01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>caja</groupId>
            <artifactId>json_simple</artifactId>
            <version>r1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <classifier>jdk13</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mlibwrapper_jai</groupId>
            <artifactId>mlibwrapper_jai</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>odmg</groupId>
            <artifactId>odmg</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>springext</groupId>
            <artifactId>springext</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0-spring3-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-compat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-tests-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some big inconsistencies in your Hibernate dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

`hibernate-c3p0` version `5.2.5.Final` lifts your required version of `hibernate-core` to be the same. The `hibernate-annotations` package has been merged into `hibernate-core` and you don't need it. You should also remove the group `org.hibernate` artifact `hibernate` version `3.5.4-Final` type `pom` dependency entirely. In fact, you only need the `hibernate-c3p0` dependency and it will add the rest.

As for the ClassNotFoundException, edit your `persistence.xml` to change the provider to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`. It has just been moved to a different package in the newer versions you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Remove the `<type>pom</type>`, and see if it works. I would advise you to follow the instructions from [Hibernate's page](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) to configure properly your pom file.